# What is the format of this data?

Tags: json, dataformat

I'm sorry if this is really trivial, but I've got a series of data as follows:

```
{"color":{"red":255,"blue":123,"green",1}}
```

I know it's in this format because, for some reason, it's easy to work with. What is this format called so that I might look it up?

\edit: If there is any significance to the organization of the data, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's JSON, a serialised text data storage based on a subset of JavaScript Object Notation. To learn more about JSON, vist: http://json.org

In JSON, there are the following data types:

- object
- array
- number
- string
- null
- boolean

Objects are represented using the following syntax, and are key-value pairings, similar to a dictionary (the key must be a string):

```
{ "number": 1, "string": "test" }
```

Like dictionaries, objects are unordered.

An array is a ordered, heterogeneous data structure, represented using the following syntax:

```
[0, true, false, "1", null]
```

Numbers are what you'd expect, however unlike JavaScript itself they cannot be `Infinity` or `NaN` (i.e. they must be decimals or integers) and contain no leading 0s. Exponents are  represented using the following format (the `e` is not case sensitive):

```
10e6
```

where `10` is the base and `6` is the exponent - this is equivalent to `1000000` (1 million). The exponent section may have leading `0`s, though there is not much point and may lower compatibility with parsers which are not 100% compliant.

Booleans are case sensitive and are both lowercase. In JSON, there are only two booleans:

```
true
false
```

To represent an intentionally left out or otherwise unknown field, use `null` (case sensitive too).

Strings must be delimited using double quotes (single quotes are invalid syntax), and single quotes need not be escaped.

```
"This string is valid, and it's alright to do this."
'No, this won't work'
'Nor will this.'
```

There are numerous escapes available using the backslash character - to use a literal backslash, use `\\`.

As JSON is a data transmission format, there is no syntax for comments available.